# Custom raster generated by gdal2tiles with leaflet

Tags: leaflet, raster, gdal, geotiff

I was able to generate a tiles folder with gdal2tiles.py which allows me to show a geotiff file on a map :
[image: geotiff add to leaflet]

And all my geotiff file generated are in gray scale and I would like to be able to color them and add a legend to see which value correspond to which color. Here is my actual code which allows me to do this :

```
    <div id="map"></div>
    <button id="populate">Populate with 10 markers</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">
var map = L.map('map').setView([45, -93], 3);

/* setting some basemap options */
var tile_options = {
    subdomains: '1234'  
};

/* the base map tile layer */

var basemap = L.tileLayer('http://otile{s}.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/map/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',tile_options);
basemap.addTo(map);

/* the georeferenced map tile layer */
var layer = L.tileLayer('./outputf/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', { maxZoom: 16,tms:true });    
map.addLayer(layer);
```

I am still looking for solution... Of if you have some better option to render a geotiff file on a map

Answer (score 1):

I was able to convert grayscale to colour using gdaldem color-relief

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/130199/changing-color-of-raster-images-based-on-their-data-values-gdal

http://www.gdal.org/gdaldem.html#gdaldem_color_relief